# Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Braintree\Block\Paypal\Button in magento2 braintree

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, braintree

I override the braintree module after that I'm getting this error. can anyone help me.

```
Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Braintree\Block\Paypal\Button
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: I just override the app/code/Magento/Braintree/Model/Ui/ConfigProvider.php file only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom module, `app/code/Module/Namespace/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento/Braintree/Model/Ui/ConfigProvider" type="your/file/path" />
</config>
```

Then place the `ConfigProvider.php` in  `Module\Namespace\Model\Ui\`  path.

Then in that file rewrite,

```
namespace Module\Namespace\Model\Ui;


/**
 * Class Form
 */

class ConfigProvider extends \Magento\Braintree\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider
{

    public function YourFunction()
    {
          #your code
    }

}
```

Comment: rewrite the file but error displaying in cart page